# Count of distinct rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to select fixed size of distinct rows (per page) from table + count of all rows (per query). There is my query without count of all rows:

```
select distinct takenBookTitle, user from Books
where user = 'username'
order by takenBookTitle
offset 0 rows fetch next 3 rows only
```

But with this result I need to retrieve count of all rows (without offset.. fetch).

If distinct wasn't necessary It would be done with **count(*) OVER()**:

```
select takenBookTitle, user, count(*) OVER() AS count 
from Books
where user = 'username'
order by takenBookTitle offset 0 rows fetch next 3 rows only
```

**Result:**

```
BookTitle1  userName1   10
BookTitle2  userName2   10
BookTitle3  userName3   10
```

But I want to count **distinct** rows but ***count(*) OVER()*** doesn't allow it.

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't use two queries here, one to get the total result count and another to retrieve individual results? Seems a bit silly to return the same information (the total count of distinct rows) with each result.

Comment: @smj the total count of distinct rows is the value which is used on client side by my datatable and I need return this value with each select query. Theoreticaly I can use separate query to select this count but in my situation it's not good way.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the `count` in another query with the same constraints (where clause) and cross join to it, since it only contains one row so the same information will be appended accordingly to every row:

```
select
  t.*, g.cnt
from (
  select distinct takenBookTitle, user from Books
  where user = 'username'
  order by user offset 0 rows fetch next 3 rows only
  ) t
cross join (
  select count(*) as cnt
  from Books
  where user = 'username'
  ) g
```

I'm wondering why are you ordering by `user` if your where clause specifies only one, but you may be using several users for this purpose and are presenting us the simplified query. If not, that order by seems unnecessary